# How to pass "/" into Node as an Argument of type string

Tags: node.js

I am trying to pass / into Node as an argument. I am doing this currently by typing `node index.js /` but it is instead referring to the root directory of my program. How can I pass this in as a string to be used within my program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass in `/` to the node script without and problems, and it will be interpreted as string.

However, node `process.argv` returns an array of arguments passed to the node.js script, your parameter will be the **third** element.
The first parameter is the path to the node executable, and the second is to the file that is being executed.

Comment: I am going through the whole `process.argv` array and none of them contain `/` only filepaths... Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: @debuff, if you put nothing at all but `console.log(process.argv)` in your `index.js` and then type `node index.js /` on the command line, you will get an array with three elements and the third one will be `"/"`.  The first element is the full path to `node.exe`, the second element is the full path to your `index.js` file and the third one is your first command line argument `"/"`.